# Wrong value sent to second view the first time it is passed from the parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In the following code, I'm trying to pass a bool to `SecondView` when a button is tapped. I'm changing the state of the bool within a `Segmented/PickerView`, what is tricking me is the fact that if I run the app, tap on the `Turned Off` segment which updates the `isRunning` bool to false, and then tap on the `Show Second View` button, I get `true` in Second View, and I was expecting `false` since it was changed within the segmented/picker view before sending it.

The funny thing is that everything starts working as expected if I tap on the `Turned Off` segment, go to Second View, come back, tap on the `Started` then tap on the `Turned Off` segment again, and show the Second View again, then I start getting the right values.

**Any idea why the first time I go to Second View after tapping on the `Turned Off` segment I get the `wrong value for` isRunning`in`Second View`?**

### Main View

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var onOffSegments = 1
    @State private var isRunning = true
        
    @State private var secondViewIsPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("", selection: $onOffSegments) {
                Text("Started")
                    .tag(1)
                Text( "Turned Off")
                    .tag(2)
            }
            .pickerStyle(.segmented)
            .onChange(of: onOffSegments, perform: { value in
                if value == 1{
                    isRunning = true
                    print("Is Running:\(isRunning)")
                }else{
                    isRunning = false
                    print("Is Running: \(isRunning)")
                }
            })
            
            Button("Show Second View"){
                secondViewIsPresented = true
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .sheet(isPresented: $secondViewIsPresented){
            SecondView(isRunning: isRunning)
        }
    }
}
```

### Second View

```
struct SecondView: View {
    var isRunning: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Second View")
            .onAppear{
                print("OnAppear SecondView, Is Running: \(isRunning)")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: use `sheet(item:)`

Comment: I tried it but I got an error that said, `Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<Bool>' to expected argument type 'Binding<Item?>'`

Comment: The optional is key, the other option is to use `@Binding var isRunning: Bool` in `SecondView` it will have the new value

Comment: This is a bug in SwiftUI. @malhal’s answer is a reasonable workaround.

Comment: @loremipsum - Using binding as you suggested `@Binding var isRunning: Bool` worked. Thanks.

Comment: @robmayoff - Thank you for pointing out the fact that this is a bug. I went with malhal's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `isRunning` getter isn't called anywhere in body it means SwiftUI's dependency tracking doesn't detect it - so it doesn't think recomputing body is required and thus doesn't call body when  `isRunning`  is set. You can force it like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $secondViewIsPresented){ [isRunning] in
```

FYI this Swift syntax is called a capture list.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you for pointing out what the syntax is called and why this is happening, I honestly would have never known what was causing the issue. Thanks a lot.